# Is it possible to pass in an array into a neural network perceptron?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to set up a neural network for identify Elliott Waves and I was wondering if it is possible to pass in an array of arrays into a perceptron? My plan is to pass in an array of size 4 ([Open, Close, High, Low]) into each perceptron. If so, how would the weighted average calculation work and how can I go about this using the Python Keras library? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly *array of arrays*. Each one of the `Open`, `Close`, ... etc. is an array? If yes, do they all have the same shape? Even if they don't you can just flatten them and pass them to the neural network without much problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant just 1 array into a perceptron. So the array that has the values [Open, Close, ... etc] would be passed into each perceptron.

Comment: Well that is the standard way that neural networks work. The calculation that you are asking is a matrix multiplication between the inputs, which have a shape of `(num_samples, 4)` and the weights, which have a shape of `(4, 1)` for regression and `(4, num_classes)` for classification. To do this in keras you need a [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/) layer. I can write an answer with more implementation details if you want.

Comment: Yeah if you can provide an example I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty standard Fully Connected Neural Network to build. I assume that you have a classification problem:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# I assume that x is the array containing the training data
# the shape of x should be (num_samples, 4)
# The array containing the test data is named y and is 
# one-hot encoded with a shape of (num_samples, num_classes)
# num_samples is the number of samples in your training set
# num_classes is the number of classes you have
# e.g. is a binary classification problem num_classes=2

# First, we'll define the architecture of the network
inp = Input(shape=(4,)) # you have 4 features
hidden = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(inp)  # 10 neurons in your hidden layer
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(hidden)  

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[out])

# Compile the model and define the loss function and optimizer
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# feel free to change these to suit your needs

# Train the model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=512)
# train the model for 10 epochs with a batch size of 512
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u got different weights for each array value?

Id think you would because they sound like different semantics by the names of the variables.

That would be the same as having 4 separate networks, but maybe it would suit making the code easier to write it this way.

So I say, the idea is good for that reason.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34956835)